# filtering list by multiple attributes

Tags: c#

I'm working on a Book Manager project.

Assume that i have Book class like this:

```
public class Book {
    public string Name;
    public List<string> Tags;
}
```

and I also have a List of Book and some checkboxes have the same value of tags for user to select which tags they will use to filtering the List of Book.

What I want is to filtering the List of Book by tags that user chose and put the result to the new List.

Example:

Book1 has {A, B, C} tags, Book2 has {A, B, D} tags and Book3 has {D, E, F} tags. So if user choose A and B tags to filter, the new list will contain Book1 and Book2. Or if they choose D tag to filter, the new list will contain Book3.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Linq:

```
List<Book> Books = yourList;
Books = Books.Where(a=>a.Tags.Where(z=>z.Intersect(userList).Any()).ToList()
```

You have use Intersect to find items in list than contains any item in another.

---

From the remarks, seems that you don't know much about Linq, the "a" and "z" are lamda expressions, which you can see it as a foreach loop:

```
Books.Where(a=>a.Tags == "a")
```

is equivalent to:

```
foreach(Book item in Books)
{
   if(item.Tags == "a")
   {
     //Add item to your result;
   }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain a=>a and z=>z for me? or maybe some documents for me to read about this? thank you!

Comment: More info on Lambda functions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: The lambda in those methods is like declaring a variable in a foreach loop over the collection, and then using that variable to reference each item as it loops through the collection. It's just shorthand for looping over the items in a collection.

Comment: one more question. Which term will do exact same thing like this in java and python?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know much about those two languages, maybe you can do some research on Google :(